# how to separate a row result to grups in TWIG

Tags: symfony, twig

Form query i have several **rows** record

Controller:

```
public function statusTaskAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $statusAll = $em->getRepository( 'MyBundle:StatusTask' )
        ->allStatusQuery();

    return [ 'rows' => $statusAll ];
}
```

statusTask.html.twig

```html
<table class="table ">
    <tbody>
    {% for entry in row %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ entry.endDate is null ? '' : entry.endDate }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.groupID }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.info }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">No rows</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

groupID displayed status:

- g - "Green"
- r - "Red"
- f - "Future to plan"
- p - "Planed"

I'll try to separate result by groupID and for this result add label, decription to each displayed grupID in TWIG and separate it in TWIG.

**How can I do it in TWIG?**

Comment: You don't, you do this in the controller

Comment: I have the feeling that this a use case for jQuery .. or for a group by in your sql request .

Comment: Is the any example how  show it in  jQuery ?

Comment: What is `row`? Does that come from your controller? You can use "@" and my name to respond to my comment. If `row` is an Entity results, then you can use getters in Twig, and you won't need jQuery.

Comment: @AlvinBunk row is is an Entity results. I supplement my question by add  the controller function.

Answer (score -1):

Since row is an Entity, you don't call the column name, but instead the Entity getters like so:

```
<table class="table ">
    <tbody>
    {% for entry in rows %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ entry.getDate is null ? '' : entry.getDate }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.getGroupID }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.getName }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.getInfo }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">No rows</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I presume that would be the naming in your Entity class for the Entity StatuTask. Also, I think you need to use `rows` as specified in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for answer @AlvinBunk I'll planet change only front-end - no logic in controller but if is not simple way to do it then I change controller.

Comment: My solution above is a `Twig` solution, not a Controller change!